# Update data in SQLite and populate ListView in fragment with it

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, android-asynctask, fragment

I'm trying to load data from Firebase to SQLite and then show it in fragment, but data shows only on second opening of fragment.

```
public class Root_Exercises_Fragment_v2 extends BaseFragment {
    public static final String TAG = "TAG1";
    private ListView mListview;
    private MyAdapter mAdapter;
    private DBHelper dbHelper;
    private SQLiteDatabase database;


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.myLayout, container, false);
        new AsyncClass().execute();
        mListview = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.mListview);
        return view;

    }

    class AsyncClass extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... parameter) {
            MyClass myClass = new MyClass(getActivity());
            myClass.myFunction();
            return null;
        }


        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            Log.v("TAG", "In postExecute");
            dbHelper = new DBHelper(getActivity());
            database = dbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
            mAdapter = new MyAdapter(getActivity(), database.rawQuery(getString(R.string.myQuery), null)) {
            };
            mListview.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        }
    }
}
```

In doInBackground function myClass.myFunction() compares data in Firebase to data in SQLite and downloads missing data from Firebase to db. It defenitely works, cause I can see it in log.
I've also tried to add notifyDataSetChanged to onPostExecute, but it didn't help.
If anyone knows why data may not show at the first opening of fragment, please, help me find a solution.

Comment: Just to be clear, can you print the size of the cursor that is being returned in `database.rawQuery()`. Print it and make sure that the size is non zero first time.

Comment: On the first openin cursor size is 0. It appears that onPostExecute start before doInBackground finishes. Is there any way to make onPostExecute wait for doInBackground to complete?

Comment: What you are saying is impossible as per Android API doc. I think you need to put the logs properly and check again

Answer (score 0):

**notifyDataSetChanged** should work.
You need to call it at the right place.

Call it from from the thread where you fill the list (in the main UI thread).

Here's an example -

```
results = ...
if(mHandler==null)
  mHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
Runnable myRunnable = new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
              mResultList.addAll(results);
              mResultListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
      }
};
mHandler.post(myRunnable);
```